# Can i delete topics as a producer? Or can i delete topics before writing them

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a producer which feeds data what we will use for testing our web application and the consumers. For that, I am asking if there is a way to delete the topics before sending them to thru producer? Currently, as I am using a VM on my computer to test out the system I can thru CMD. Is there any way to do it by the producer program. (Java)

Comment: Do you use persistent consumer offset tracking? If so, this might confuse them.

Comment: While i am doing in my computer i am also deleting offset topic in the VM where kafka is running. So afaik it starts from beginning.  (I hope i understood the question right). In the future i would use the same setup if possible. The problem being i would alot of data to another program which writes it into mongodb where our webapplication will read it from.

Comment: You should definitely not touch the offsets topic. It'll reset more than just your one application, and I don't understand the question. Your producer won't work if a topic doesn't exist

Comment: I am creating the topics while i write with the producer. I clean out all my topics and delete the offset topic also. As only 1 program will be in touch with the kafka i am running that is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can include some code that deletes topics within your Producer implementation (probably in the very beginning).

Here's one [example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=kafka.admin.AdminUtils&method=deleteTopic) that makes use of `kafka.admin.AdminUtils.deleteTopic()`,

```
/**
 * Deletes the named topics
 * @param topicNames The names of the topics to delete
 * @return A set of the names of the topics that were successfully deleted
 */
public String[] deleteTopics(final String...topicNames) {
    if(!connected.get()) throw new IllegalStateException("The KafkaTestServer is not running");
    if(topicNames==null || topicNames.length==0) return new String[0];
    final Set<String> deleted = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    for(String topicName: topicNames) {
        if(topicName==null || topicName.trim().isEmpty()) {
            try {
                AdminUtils.deleteTopic(zkUtils, topicName.trim());
                deleted.add(topicName.trim());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.warn("Failed to delete topic [" + topicName.trim() + "]", ex);
            }
        }
    }
    return deleted.toArray(new String[deleted.size()]);
}
```

Comment: So i can delete a topic (which is not in my computers zookeeper/kafka)  from my producer?

Comment: In the same class you are going to use both Producer API and AdminUtils.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, though, because you would then need to run AdminClient (which should be used instead of AdminUtils) to create the topic before a producer could use it

Comment: I tried to look into it, but i am not using AdminUtils or AdminClient. I am sending the topics in my mainclass while giving the info to a Kafkaproducer. Looks like this : 
final Producer<SpecificRecord, SpecificRecord> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props,
    new AvroSerializer<>(registry), new AvroSerializer<>(registry));